# Restrict the size of built-in types

Tags: c, gcc, embedded

The company I work for used to produce and maintain small embedded systems based on a 68k processor.  We'd like to move forward and stop maintaining those in favor of something like a Raspberry Pi, so I'm working on porting the inhouse library that was used to write software for these devices so that the programs can be crosscompiled for Linux.

The issue I've encountered is that the specification for these devices maintains strict type sizes, namely 16-bit for short and 32-bit for int and long.  Because the C specification only defines minimum sizes for types and our users were scientists with little "proper coding" education we run into situations like this all over user code:

```
typedef struct {
    short int a;
    short int b;
} Pair;
...
Pair * p=malloc(4);
```

If it can be avoided, we'd rather not have our users extensively rewrite their programs.  Recompiling GCC to accomplish this might be an option but I'd like to know it's possible before I try because I don't want to waste effort.  So my question is basically "Is there some way in GCC or another compiler to force types to a certain size"?

Comment: you can use `int16_t` and similar types.

Comment: I'm aware that the "right" fix is for users to go through their source code and replace "int" with "int16_t" and the like but I'm mostly looking for a solution that does not require our dozens of outside companies to rewrite thousands of lines of source code.

Comment: Seems like a non-issue to me. The existing SW expects 16-bit short and 32-bit int and long. Have you found something that says that a Raspberry Pi doesn't have a 16-bit short and 32-bit int and long? Point is that the spec is irrelevant here. Your task is to select hardware that complies with the requirement that shorts are 16-bit, and int and long 32-bits. That's pretty much any 32-bit system, which AFAIK includes the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: IMHO you should go for the "right fix", through a script that will patch your code with the appropriate type. A workaround _might_ save some time at the moment but will more likely prove to be not worthy eventually.

Comment: @user3386109 It is an issue because the hardware is out my control.  I used the Raspberry Pi as an example because it's what they're leaning towards as a general replacement.  I know at least some users want to leverage existing BeagleBone boards or spare x86 or AMD64 desktops. The problem exists because I can't guarantee the type sizes through hardware because I can't possibly predict all the hardware someone might want to use.

Comment: For the x86, there's a `-m32` option that forces GCC to emit 32-bit code even when targeting a 64-bit processor. Not sure if that option works with other processors.

Comment: `-mx32` emits x86_64 code but keeps `long` 32-bit. [GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options).

Comment: @coconop This is very much legacy maintenance for users who can't afford or won't approve moving to our newer systems, which is why we're trying to minimize the time and effort it takes to for them to update.  No new code is under active development, and I suggest most of the existing code hasn't even been recompiled since the early 90's when it was written, so we've accepted that a hacky solution that's done once and gets us another 25 years of usage is probably ok.

Comment: Btw, `malloc` wants the size in bytes, not in bits. If that's the real code, maybe you don't need to change anything :S

Comment: @mafso Gah and I _dare_ to say I write C code for a living.  Edited.

Comment: @SteveRoschard so the short of it is: you'll quietly kick the can down the road rather than crush it if the opportunity presents itself. I wonder if that was in the back of someone's mind in the early 90's. It guess the saying "There's never enough time to do it right, but always enough to do it over" isn't really true. Often there isn't enough time to do *either*. Best of luck, sir. Hope you catch a break.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh I'm a very pedantic person and **I** very much want to crush that can and tell them to fix their code.  Unfortunately, that's not my decision to make.  I can only hope that our users move away from the platform and some poor soul 2 decades from now isn't maintaining 50-year old process control code.  (I'm not particularly keen on making a bet on that though)

Comment: Unfortunately the moment has passed, otherwise you could have employed the Rahm Emanuel philosophy: "You never let a serious crisis go to waste. And what I mean by that it's an opportunity to do things you think you could not do before." Darn it all to hell. As i said, I hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like

`#define short int16_t`

`#define int int32_t`

etc, and add it to the program. This is a really ugly solution, but it does what you need.

These types have a specific size mandated by the standard. You'd need to include `stdint.h` for these types to be available. They are part of the C standard as of C99.

**EDIT**: the C preprocessor can't handle it with old-style `short int` / `long int` namings. For these cases, I recommend making a small script to go through the source files and replace all occurences of `int` with `int32_t`, all occurences of `short` **and** `short int` with `int16_t`, etc.

**EDIT on another second thought**: anyway, the example you gave can fail for a different reason: the struct uses *padding*, which can make its actual size larger than the sum of the sizes of its contents. So, to make the solution portable, you'd need to go through such `malloc` calls as in the example and use the `sizeof` operator in them (in your example, you'd want to make the code like this: `Pair * p=malloc(sizeof(Pair));`), **or** you can use a dirtier solution and make all structs *packed*, and the syntaxis for that can be compiler dependand.

Comment: This was one of the first solutions we thought of, but some of the client code uses the older style of type declarations like short int var  and long int var so simple defines often don't work.

Comment: @SteveRoschard: well, that, I think, leaves the most obvious solution: make a small script to go through the source files and replace all occurences of `int` with `int32_t`, all occurences of `short` and `short int` with `int16_t`, etc.